# I am working on a Flutter app that reads data from a BLE device

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on a Flutter app that reads data from a BLE device, and the device sends data when I write a command to it. If I want to receive the latest data, should I keep sending the command periodically, or is there a different approach?

Please let me know the best approach for receiving the latest data from the BLE device

Answer (score 0):

If the data keeps comming from BLE devices, this plugin might be useful for you: [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus)

In "[Set notifications and listen to changes](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus#set-notifications-and-listen-to-changes)" section:

```
// Setup Listener for characteristic reads

final subscription = characteristic.onValueReceived.listen((value) {
    // do something with new value
});
```